# How to profile Guice configure method

Tags: java, profiling, guice

I want to get a list of all the modules installed in my application and the time the configure() method in each of them takes.

Can I get this information with a profiler?

Can I instrument the configure method somehow with AOP?

Thanks!

Comment: You certainly can't do it with Guice's AOP functionality because it only applies to instances created by Guice.  I'd just put timing code in all your configure methods.

Answer (score 1):

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) has such functionality. You can set up a method trigger for the configure method. In general, this is most easily done by clicking "Add method trigger" for a profiled method in the call tree view or by selecting the method from the class browser. The screen shot below shows the manual configuration with the method signature that has to be intercepted in this case.

[image]

In the trigger actions, add a "Run interceptor script" action and set the "On method entry" script. In the script you can access the current object with the "currentObject" parameter. You can now print the class names or call your own code to save it to a list.

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just editing Guice, it was the quickest way to get the results that I knew of. JProfiler would of came in handy. Thanks